# Deleting repeated strings in a list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, date

How can I write a function that deletes any repeated strings. In the list `dates` the strings `'2017-11-01 00:00:00','2018-12-01 00:00:00'` has been repeated twice or more. I want to get it to the point where it is of the `Expected Output` and where there is only 1 case for each string.

```
dates = ['2017-09-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-02-01 00:00:00', '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '2018-04-01 00:00:00', '2018-05-01 00:00:00', '2018-06-01 00:00:00', '2018-07-01 00:00:00', '2018-08-01 00:00:00', '2018-09-01 00:00:00', '2018-10-01 00:00:00', '2018-11-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Expected Output:

```
['2017-09-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00', '2017-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-02-01 00:00:00', '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '2018-04-01 00:00:00', '2018-05-01 00:00:00', '2018-06-01 00:00:00', '2018-07-01 00:00:00', '2018-08-01 00:00:00', '2018-09-01 00:00:00', '2018-10-01 00:00:00', '2018-11-01 00:00:00', '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Comment: `list(dict.fromkeys(dates))`?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny smart ;) you should have proposed as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to filter out **consecutives** repeats, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[dates[0]]+[dates[i] for i in range(1, len(dates)) if dates[i-1]!=dates[i]]
```

or [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
[list(g)[0] for i,g in groupby(dates)]
```

output:

```
['2017-09-01 00:00:00', '2017-10-01 00:00:00', '2017-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2017-12-01 00:00:00', '2018-01-01 00:00:00', '2018-02-01 00:00:00',
 '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '2018-04-01 00:00:00', '2018-05-01 00:00:00',
 '2018-06-01 00:00:00', '2018-07-01 00:00:00', '2018-08-01 00:00:00',
 '2018-09-01 00:00:00', '2018-10-01 00:00:00', '2018-11-01 00:00:00',
 '2018-12-01 00:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Comment: Thank you it works, is there a way I could do it with `integers` instead of `strings`. I tried `[int(g)[0] for i,g in groupby(month_changes)]` with a list numbers like `[2,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, it gives me this error msg `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'itertools._grouper'`

Comment: It should work with integers, just use the exact same code. The`list` is here to expand the group generator.